# How to show in the same legend data points (geom_point) and lines (from stat_ecdf)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After estimating the parameters of a distribution through bootstrapping, starting from "known" data (i.e., coming from the literature, experiments, and so on) for wihch the teoretical distribution is known, I want to display on the same plot the original data (with associated cumulative probability), and the CDFs of both the "true" distribution and the estimated one.

However, I am failing to display data and curves in the same legend.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
  libary(ggplot2)

  n.studies <- 50
  cumulative.prob <- seq(1 / n.studies, 1 - 1 / n.studies, length.out = n.studies)
  known.values <- qnorm(cumulative.prob)
  group <- rep(c("Source 1", "Source 2", "Source 3"), length.out = n.studies)
  data <- data.frame(x = known.values, y = cumulative.prob, group = group)
  # Simulate the bootstrap procedure
  sampler <- function(x) {
    bootstrap <- sample(x = known.values, size = length(known.values), replace = T)
    return(c(mean = mean(bootstrap), sd = sd(bootstrap)))
  }
  simulated.statistics <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(rep(1, 10000), sampler)))
  simulated.dist <- data.frame("Simulated" = rnorm(10000, mean = mean(simulated.statistics$mean), sd = mean(simulated.statistics$sd)),
                               "LCL" = rnorm(10000, mean = quantile(simulated.statistics$mean, .025, names = F), sd = mean(simulated.statistics$sd)),
                               "UCL" = rnorm(10000, mean = quantile(simulated.statistics$mean, .975, names = F), sd = mean(simulated.statistics$sd)),
                               "Original" = rnorm(10000))
  # Plot data and CDFs
  g <- ggplot() +
    stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = Simulated), colour = "darkgreen", linetype = "solid", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
    stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = LCL), colour = "lightgreen", linetype = "dashed", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
    stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = UCL), colour = "lightgreen", linetype = "dashed", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
    stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = Original), colour = "red", linetype = "dotted", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group, shape = group)) +
    xlab("Value") + 
    ylab("CDF") +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.title = element_blank())
  print(g)
```

[image: resulting chart]

What I want to obtain is exactly this graph, with a legend displaying in addition to the data points (exactly as they are) the four curves (i.e. two "dashed lightgreen" curves labeled as "LCL" and "UCL", a "solid darkgreen" curve labeled "Simulated", and a "red dotted" curve labeled "Original").
So far I tried to manually set legends for colors, shapes and linetypes, but I am either obtaining "more than one legend" or an incorrect graph (e.g., points or curves are disappearing), I suppose this is due to the fact that stat_ecdf and geom_point do not share the same aesthetics.

Thank you in advance for your precious help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an elegant solution focused on [tidying](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) the `simulated.dist` dataset, but the one below seems to get the job done.

Ultimately, OP wants two legends:

1. One that shows the points and their colors, and
2. One that shows the lines and their colors.

The "tidy" solution would be to make use of all aesthetics mapped to the data, but this actually makes things a bit cumbersome.  Instead, with this example I will concede on some mapping to make adjustment a bit more straightforward.  The most problematic aesthetic here is `color`, which would be shared across the two legends.  Therefore, the solution I present is to ensure they are not shared:  color is mapped with `geom_point()` already, so we'll keep the color "not-mapped" for the `stat_ecdf()` lines.  Unfortunately, this means we cannot combine the `stat_ecdf()` calls into one common line: hence the cumbersome solution.

To get a legend showing for the `stat_ecdf()`, we need to map *something* into `aes()`.  Here I'm using `linetype=` since this is not an aesthetic in `geom_point()`, so it's an easy way to keep the legends separate.  By doing this, `ggplot2` will decide to reorder our legend items alphabetically, and also will not apply color to the lines in the legend to match the panel.  Therefore, I will have to specify the order and colors of the legend keys manually using `override.aes()`.  We also need to specify the actual linetypes.  We do all this via the `scale_linetype_manual()` and `guides()` functions.

```
g1 <- ggplot() +
  stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = Simulated, linetype="Simulated"), colour = "darkgreen", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = LCL, linetype="LCL"), colour = "lightgreen", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = UCL, linetype="UCL"), colour = "lightgreen", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
  stat_ecdf(data = simulated.dist, aes(x = Original, linetype="Original"), colour = "red", geom = "step", lwd = 1) + 
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group, shape = group)) +
  xlab("Value") + 
  ylab("CDF") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    limits=c("Simulated", "LCL", "UCL", "Original"),
    values=c("Simulated"="solid", "LCL" = "dashed", "UCL" = "dashed", "Original" = "dotted")
  ) +
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(
    override.aes = list(
      color=c("darkgreen", "lightgreen", "lightgreen", "red"))
  ))

g1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for both the answer and the introduction: the second paragraph also explains to me why my previous attempts (not reported here) were failing. I confess I was hoping for a "tidy solution" (which I was not able to find), but the proposed solution works and is clear. I am marking it as accepted answer.